# AWS ECS cluster: Create second instance, move containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I have AWS ECS cluster with with one instance.

[image]

This instance has four containers (2 staging, 2 production):

[image]

How can I create a second instance and move two containers production to new instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you've chosen to have such setup for staging and production environment ? If something goes wrong in staging container, production also will be affected.

Create 2 Clusters and 2 Fargate Tasks, for staging environment to be used staging image and for production the production one.

Don't build monolithic things ….